# How to limit a filter to some rows only in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

When adding a filter to an Excel spreadsheet, how do I limit its scope to some rows only?

For instance, in this document:

[image]

the “Hello” column filter will contain the values 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9 and 27. How can I make the sum, that is the value 27, disappear from the values suggested by the filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I can think of is by adding a blank row between the numbers and the sum. This way you can limit your filter to just the numbers.

[image]

Comment: Adding an empty row just adds another element `(Empty)` to the filter list. The sum is still there.

Comment: Remove the filter and reapply the filter.

Comment: Perfect. It works now.